# Upload ZipArchive file to AWS S3 without Saving to Directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, php-ziparchive

My script takes files that have been passed into a function, and combines/saves them as a compressed file using ZipArchive onto the directory on my server.

Then I upload the zipped file to an AWS S3 bucket, and delete the uploaded file off my server.

However, is there a way to save the ZipArchive as a variable or temporary file and upload it directly to AWS without saving to and then deleting from my server?

```
$files = $_GET['json'];
$zipFolder = new ZipArchive;
$zipPath = "folder/compressedfile.zip";
if ($zipFolder->open($zipPath, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {           
        $textString = $file['text'];
        $zipFolder->addFromString($file['name'] . '.txt', $textString);
    }     
}
$zipFolder->close();

$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'region'      => '--region--',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '--key--',
        'secret' => '--secret--',
    ],

]);

$bucketName = '--bucket--';

$result = $s3Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucketName,
    'Key'    => 'compressedfile.zip',
    'SourceFile' => $zipPath            
]);

unlink($zipPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stream data from memory to an S3 object. You don't have to upload a file from disk.

Take a look at the [S3 Stream Wrapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html) as one option.